# Fetching the childrens by id from the json tree structure data

Tags: javascript

I am using JS to archive the following functionality.

My json data

```
data=[{"id":63,"parent":59,"currency":1},{"id":64,"parent":59,"currency":1},
{"id":1,"parent":null,"currency":1},{"id":2,"parent":1,"currency":4},
{"id":4,"parent":3,"currency":4},{"id":3,"parent":2,"currency":2},
{"id":5,"parent":1,"currency":5},{"id":6,"parent":1,"currency":6},
{"id":7,"parent":3,"currency":2},{"id":8,"parent":1,"currency":1},
{"id":57,"parent":56,"currency":1},{"id":58,"parent":1,"currency":1},
{"id":59,"parent":1,"currency":1},{"id":30,"parent":1,"currency":1},
{"id":31,"parent":1,"currency":1},{"id":32,"parent":1,"currency":1},
{"id":33,"parent":1,"currency":1},{"id":34,"parent":1,"currency":1},
{"id":35,"parent":1,"currency":1},{"id":36,"parent":1,"currency":18},
{"id":37,"parent":1,"currency":1},{"id":39,"parent":1,"currency":1},
{"id":41,"parent":6,"currency":6},{"id":42,"parent":1,"currency":1},
{"id":43,"parent":42,"currency":1},{"id":48,"parent":47,"currency":2},
{"id":47,"parent":37,"currency":2},{"id":49,"parent":48,"currency":2},
{"id":52,"parent":1,"currency":16},{"id":9,"parent":1,"currency":9},
{"id":54,"parent":1,"currency":4},{"id":55,"parent":1,"currency":1},
{"id":56,"parent":1,"currency":1},{"id":19,"parent":1,"currency":12},
{"id":21,"parent":1,"currency":1},{"id":12,"parent":1,"currency":1},
{"id":13,"parent":1,"currency":1},{"id":15,"parent":1,"currency":1},
{"id":16,"parent":1,"currency":1},{"id":10,"parent":1,"currency":8},
{"id":11,"parent":1,"currency":4},{"id":66,"parent":1,"currency":1},
{"id":69,"parent":68,"currency":1},{"id":65,"parent":1,"currency":1},
{"id":68,"parent":1,"currency":1},{"id":70,"parent":1,"currency":11}]
```

What I am trying to archive:

1. The Js code should fetch all the "ids" of the children and grandchildren of the inputted "id" and form as new json key(children).
2. If there is no children found then add their own "id" in children array

if my input is "id" = 59

my resulted json data:

```
resulteddata = [{"id":59,"currency":1,"children":[59,63,64]}
```

if my input is "id" = 1

my resulted json data:

```
resulteddata = [{"id":1,"currency":1,"children":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 ...... 70]} // all the children and grand children
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
data = [{"id":63,"parent":59,"currency":1},{"id":64,"parent":59,"currency":1},{"id":1,"parent":null,"currency":1},{"id":2,"parent":1,"currency":4},{"id":4,"parent":3,"currency":4},{"id":3,"parent":2,"currency":2},{"id":5,"parent":1,"currency":5},{"id":6,"parent":1,"currency":6},{"id":7,"parent":3,"currency":2},{"id":8,"parent":1,"currency":1},{"id":57,"parent":56,"currency":1},{"id":58,"parent":1,"currency":1},{"id":59,"parent":1,"currency":1},{"id":30,"parent":1,"currency":1},{"id":31,"parent":1,"currency":1},{"id":32,"parent":1,"currency":1},{"id":33,"parent":1,"currency":1},{"id":34,"parent":1,"currency":1},{"id":35,"parent":1,"currency":1},{"id":36,"parent":1,"currency":18},{"id":37,"parent":1,"currency":1},{"id":39,"parent":1,"currency":1},{"id":41,"parent":6,"currency":6},{"id":42,"parent":1,"currency":1},{"id":43,"parent":42,"currency":1},{"id":48,"parent":47,"currency":2},{"id":47,"parent":37,"currency":2},{"id":49,"parent":48,"currency":2},{"id":52,"parent":1,"currency":16},{"id":9,"parent":1,"currency":9},{"id":54,"parent":1,"currency":4},{"id":55,"parent":1,"currency":1},{"id":56,"parent":1,"currency":1},{"id":19,"parent":1,"currency":12},{"id":21,"parent":1,"currency":1},{"id":12,"parent":1,"currency":1},{"id":13,"parent":1,"currency":1},{"id":15,"parent":1,"currency":1},{"id":16,"parent":1,"currency":1},{"id":10,"parent":1,"currency":8},{"id":11,"parent":1,"currency":4},{"id":66,"parent":1,"currency":1},{"id":69,"parent":68,"currency":1},{"id":65,"parent":1,"currency":1},{"id":68,"parent":1,"currency":1},{"id":70,"parent":1,"currency":11}]

function children(id, data) {
    return data.filter(e => e.parent === id).flatMap(e => [e.id, ...children(e.id, data)])
}

function find(id, data) {
    return {
        ...data.find(e => e.id === id),
        children: children(id, data).sort((a, b) => a === b ? 0 : a > b ? 1 : -1)
    };
}

console.log(find(1, data))
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple function to get what you are looking for. To improve time complexity you can remove sort if that is something you do not need.

```
const newJson = (id) => {
  const currency = data.find(data => data.id === id).currency;
  
  const children = getChildren(id)
  return {id, currency, children};
}


const getChildren = (id) => {
  const children = [];
  data.forEach(el => {
    if(el.parent === id){
      children.push(el.id);
    }
  })

  if(!children.includes(id)) children.push(id);
  
  return children.sort((a, b) => a-b);
}
```

Comment: This code is not fetch the grandchildren of the json array, Other than that this is perfect.